# Using sendBroadcast with intent having action "android.rfid.INPUT"

Tags: java, android, nfc, rfid

I am new to Android development and trying to debug and understand the application that runs on Android to scan barcodes. Please see [SotfScanService.java](https://github.com/xuanyuanpang/hwsoftscan/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rfid/hwsoftscan/SotfScanService.java#L335) for full source code.

The following method is supposed to send scanned barcode data with appended suffix somewhere. But I cannot figure out where. I assume it sends to an application or applications that are subscribed to that particular intent.

1. Can someone please explain what happens when `sendBroadcast()` is executed below?
2. Is `android.rfid.INPUT` a standard action that other applications understand?

I am debugging this application because web page running in the browser on Android device doesn't receive scanned barcode as `keydown`/`keypress` events and only appended suffix when input focus is not on a text box.

**SotfScanService.java:**

```
private void sendToInput(String data , boolean enterFlag){
    String result = getfixChar(data);


    String append = getAppendChar();
    switch (append) {
        case "1":
            enterFlag = true ;
            break ;
        case "2":
            result += "\n";
            break ;
        case "3":
            result += "\t";
            break ;
        case "4":

            break ;
    }

    Intent toBack = new Intent() ;
    toBack.setAction("android.rfid.INPUT") ;
    toBack.putExtra("data", result );//发送添加前缀后缀的数据
    toBack.putExtra("enter", enterFlag) ;
    sendBroadcast(toBack) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `sendBroadcast`

   Before going to `sendBroadcast`, we first need to know what a [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) is. Android apps can send or receive broadcast messages from the Android system and other Android apps, similar to the publish-subscribe design pattern. These broadcasts are sent when an event of interest occurs. For example, the Android system sends broadcasts when various system events occur, such as when the system boots up or the device starts charging. Apps can also send custom broadcasts, for example, to notify other apps of something that they might be interested in (for example, some new data has been downloaded).

   From the GitHub repo of the code, I roughly went through from the beginning to the end, it seems like an app for automation which involves scanning something (RFID? barcode?). I have commented out the process before this method as well as after this method, details are as follow.

   ```
   private void sendToInput(String data , boolean enterFlag){

       //getfixChar(data): It gets and processes data which stored in SharedPreferences Strings, 
       //namely prefix_config and suffix_config. 
       //The return value will be the data with prefix and suffix (prefix + data + suffix)
       String result = getfixChar(data);

       //getAppendChar(): It get the String stored in SharedPreference, which is append_ending_char, with default value 4.
       //If there's no value stored in append_ending_char, it will return 4, and otherwise (1, 2, or 3)
       String append = getAppendChar();
       switch (append) {
           case "1":
               enterFlag = true ;
               break ;
           case "2":
               result += "\n";
               break ;
           case "3":
               result += "\t";
               break ;
           case "4":

               break ;
       }
       //After getting and processing all the values and stored in result and append respectively.
       //The values are stored in the Intent extra, namely data and enter.
       //It will be send via Broadcast
       Intent toBack = new Intent() ;
       toBack.setAction("android.rfid.INPUT") ;
       toBack.putExtra("data", result ) ;//发送添加前缀后缀的数据 //Translation: Sending data with prefix and suffix added
       toBack.putExtra("enter", enterFlag) ;
       sendBroadcast(toBack) ;
   }
   ```
2. `android.rfid.INPUT`

   The author simply named it that way, other applications do not know about it, unless the other app receiving the same broadcast with the exact name `android.rfid.INPUT`. broadcasts can be used as a messaging system across apps and outside of the normal user flow which the developer intends to receive the broadcast sent with the ScanBroadcast method. w/o applying the code, and by just studying the flow, I think it's kinda a method for automation, depending on the result received from the intent mentioned before this.
3. Last, but not least, I would suggest you to print out all the values into the `logcat` (debugging console/terminal), so that you can know which part goes wrong.

   For example:

   ```
   private void sendToInput(String data , boolean enterFlag){
       String result = getfixChar(data);
       Log.d("result", result);

       String append = getAppendChar();
       Log.d("append", append);
       switch (append) {
           case "1":
               enterFlag = true ;
               break ;
           case "2":
               result += "\n";
               break ;
           case "3":
               result += "\t";
               break ;
           case "4":

               break ;
       }
       //Last but not least, double check here.
       Log.d("result2", result);
       Log.d("enterFlag", enterFlag);
       Intent toBack = new Intent() ;
       toBack.setAction("android.rfid.INPUT") ;
       toBack.putExtra("data", result );//发送添加前缀后缀的数据
       toBack.putExtra("enter", enterFlag.toString()) ;
       sendBroadcast(toBack) ;
   }
   ```

   As you may know, I do not have the input equipment as well as the scanning data objects, so this is the furthest I can possibly help.